# Why do cached embeddings and regular forward pass take the same time in DistilbertForSequenceClassification?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

I'm training a DistilBERT model in PyTorch and I've noticed something strange. I cached the output embeddings from the DistilBERT layer to speed up the training process. However, the training loop's speed seems unaffected.

Here's how I cached the embeddings:

```
# Create DataLoader
dataset = TensorDataset(inputs.input_ids, inputs.attention_mask, labels)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2)

# Model
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

cached_bert_outputs = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
        input_ids, attention_mask, _ = batch
        bert_outputs = model.distilbert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        cached_bert_outputs.append(bert_outputs.last_hidden_state)
```

And here's where I use these cached embeddings in the training loop:

## Training loop

```
for epoch in range(3):
    total_loss = 0.0
    num_batches = 0
    for batch, cached_output in zip(tqdm(dataloader), cached_bert_outputs):
        input_ids, attention_mask, labels = batch
        outputs = model(inputs_embeds=cached_output, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
    
    loss = outputs.loss
    total_loss += loss.item()
    num_batches += 1
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Additionally, I tested the speed for both inputs_embeds and input_ids and they seem to take the same time:

```
%%time
model(inputs_embeds=input_embeds, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
>>> Wall time: 976ms
%%time
model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
>>> Wall time: 902ms
```

Both of these take the same time to execute. Why is that the case? Shouldn't the cached embeddings make the training faster?

Comment: You should check what exactly `inputs_embeds` is doing. I believe `inputs_embeds` are expected to be input embeddings (ie in place of integer inputs), not cached output embeddings.